# Add margin on both sides of free space(background) in Html - css page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add margin on both sides of free space in Html. and fill background in the middle remaining part only.

But this id doesn't work when i put it in body tag.

```
#bodyid{
    display: block;
    margin-left:  100px;
    margin-right:  100px;
    background-color: #E3EAEA;
}
```

above given colors are random. Result should be like this.

[image: capture[![this should be the result]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4S1s.png)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make body white and add a container `div`. Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/p1mz721k/

Comment: Just one thing. Why did you remove  display:block though?

Comment: @SamarYadav 
I'm not sure :) Probably in the process, I forgot to uncomment it. It's ok to leave it there, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<style>
body {margin:0; padding:0; background:#fff;}
#container{
width:800px;
height:100%;
display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #E3EAEA;
border-left:4px #000 solid;
border-right:4px #000 solid;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a height specified? Or is there content in this div?

```
#bodyid {
    display: block;
    background-color: #E3EAEA;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the body tag but remove the CSS for it and add a div in it. Set the width of the div 80% and the margin-right and margin-left 10% each. Then add your color to the div. Also set the height of the div 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Can you fix the width of your content (pink div)?.

If so, try:

```
.pinkDiv {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you have right now is not completely doing what you want, you'll have to specify the size of the foreground(apparently there is no foreground specified) in you're CSS), based on which you can manage the background. Think from the foreground perspective, size the foreground (colored area) such that you get required margin both the sides.

I have implemented you're requirrement [here](http://codepen.io/RakshithNM/pen/vXOOag).

```
<body>
    <div id = "blck"></div>
</body>

#blck{
    width: 1050px;
    height: 1050px;
    display: block;
    background: red;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

PS: This implementation is for a 1280px wide screen. The width of the div is 1050px because you're requirement was 100px margin on both sides and the div implicitly has 15px margin.